# Kabbalos Shabbos

Tags: kabbalat-shabbat

Can one recite Kabbalos Shabbos with lekha dodi etc alone at home without minyan tzibbur or is it strictly a Shul service ? I don't live in the city but outside in a isolated area far from city or any shul, that's why i'm asking. Or alone at home does he just usher in and sanctify shabbos by reciting just Mizmor shir l'yom hashabbos and with Maariv Shabbos and Kiddush ?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Niel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You can definitely say kabalat Shabbat alone, the parts that require a minyan are kedusha, kaddish, Torah reading. But kabalat Shabbat is mostly tehilim (psalms) and those can definitely be recited alone. Same with Lekha Dodi.

Comment: All this being said this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this.

Comment: Ashaynem dank for your time to respond. I understand, i've reached out to a couple of rovs via online but haven't heard back from them. They're really busy and have many things to tend to. And it's hard also in a isolated town far from city or any shul. I understand fully what you are telling me though.

Comment: @mbloch Ashaynem dank for your welcoming me to this site. I have been on here quite often but only signed up for first time today. That's good to know, i wasn't sure about the entire Kabbalos Shabbos service at home so for a while i've just been reciting Tehilla 92, Kiddush, Maariv shabbos every Friday at home. Thank you for clearing it up for me.

Comment: Here’s a start for many of your questions. https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol16Issue5.pdf

Comment: @Chatzkel Just checked it out, Ashaynem dank for all you guys support. Very much appreciated and grateful.